# Format .csv file using SSIS

Tags: csv, ssis, pivot, ssis-2012

I have .csv file like this:

```
+---------+--------+--------------------+---------+-----+----------+----------------+
| CLIENTE | CENTRO |      MATERIAL      | PERIODO | MES | UNIDADES |   PLATAFORMA   |
+---------+--------+--------------------+---------+-----+----------+----------------+
|  100013 |   2001 | 1A000-991801053303 |    2017 |   1 |      100 | F25 -( BMW X3) |
|  100013 |   2001 | 1A000-991801053303 |    2017 |   2 |      200 | F25 -( BMW X3) |
|  100013 |   2001 | 1A000-991801053303 |    2017 |   3 |      300 | F25 -( BMW X3) |
|  100013 |   2001 | 1A000-991801053303 |    2017 |   4 |      400 | F25 -( BMW X3) |
|  100013 |   2001 | 1A000-991801053303 |    2017 |   5 |      500 | F25 -( BMW X3) |
|  100013 |   2001 | 1A000-991801053303 |    2017 |   6 |      600 | F25 -( BMW X3) |
|  100013 |   2001 | 1A000-991801053303 |    2017 |   7 |      700 | F25 -( BMW X3) |
|  100013 |   2001 | 1A000-991801053303 |    2017 |   8 |      800 | F25 -( BMW X3) |
|  100013 |   2001 | 1A000-991801053303 |    2017 |   9 |      900 | F25 -( BMW X3) |
|  100013 |   2001 | 1A000-991801053303 |    2017 |  10 |     1000 | F25 -( BMW X3) |
|  100013 |   2001 | 1A000-991801053303 |    2017 |  11 |     1100 | F25 -( BMW X3) |
|  100013 |   2001 | 1A000-991801053303 |    2017 |  12 |     1200 | F25 -( BMW X3) |
+---------+--------+--------------------+---------+-----+----------+----------------+
```

and I read it without problems with flat file source and finally send to ADO NET Destination. Problem is our client want to read registers of other way. Their .csv file is formatted like:

```
+---------+--------+--------------------+----------------+--+----------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| CLIENTE | CENTRO |      MATERIAL      |   PLATAFORMA   |  |  2017-1  | 2017-2  | 2017-3  | 2017-4 | 2017-5  | 2017-6  | 2017-7  | 2017-8  | 2017-9  | 2017-10 | 2017-11 | 2017-12 |
+---------+--------+--------------------+----------------+--+----------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|  100013 |   2001 | 1A000-991801053303 | F25 -( BMW X3) |  |      100 |     200 |     300 |     400 |     500 |     600 |     700 |     800 |     900 |    1000 |    1100 |    1200 |
|  100013 |   2001 | 1A000-991801053303 | F25 -( BMW X3) |  |          |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
|  100013 |   2001 | 1A000-991801053303 | F25 -( BMW X3) |  |          |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
|  100013 |   2001 | 1A000-991801053303 | F25 -( BMW X3) |  |          |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
|  100013 |   2001 | 1A000-991801053303 | F25 -( BMW X3) |  |          |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
|  100013 |   2001 | 1A000-991801053303 | F25 -( BMW X3) |  |          |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
|  100013 |   2001 | 1A000-991801053303 | F25 -( BMW X3) |  |          |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
|  100013 |   2001 | 1A000-991801053303 | F25 -( BMW X3) |  |          |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
|  100013 |   2001 | 1A000-991801053303 | F25 -( BMW X3) |  |          |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
|  100013 |   2001 | 1A000-991801053303 | F25 -( BMW X3) |  |          |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
|  100013 |   2001 | 1A000-991801053303 | F25 -( BMW X3) |  |          |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
|  100013 |   2001 | 1A000-991801053303 | F25 -( BMW X3) |  |          |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
+---------+--------+--------------------+----------------+--+----------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

So first registers of column five: `2017-10` and `100` correspond to first row of another 4 columns  `2017-11` and `200` to second row and so on...

As you can see first 4 columns are the same, but column 5 not. They merge column `PERIODO` and `MES` and below it we have column `UNIDADES`. that I want to is how to format it this .csv and format as first one.

**So in conclusion I want to convert second .csv file into first one**

I read that I can achieve it using PIVOT. But I really don´t understand how to use it. I search for tutorials about it and I don´t found nothing similar that I want to do.

Actual SSIS package:

[Package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7vdJ.png)

Comment: You can convert rows to column using SQL server Pivot relational operators. Instead of performing this task using SSIS do it using SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Unpivot transformation. This image from VS BIDS 2008.
You can then use the pivotkey value to create rows in your destination table
[image]

Comment: That sounds good, I try it and it works but now, what about "UNIDADES" column? how can I revert it to column too?